# Wordpress rewrite Custom post type post url

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type called `articls` using [Custom Post Type](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) UI plugin.
Now I can access the custom post using URL like

```
https://example.com.au/articles/pot-name-1/
```

But I want access them like beloved URL

```
https://example.com.au/articles/2018/01/post-name-1/
```

Comment: Find a solution with https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

Answer (score 0):

Try visit Settings » Permalinks page and scroll down to ‘Permalink Settings for Custom Post Types’ section. Here you can change the permalink structure of single items in your custom post type.